# 3D Image Rotator

Tags: silverlight, flash, image, 3d, rotator

I have been tasked with creating a 3d product viewer.  The viewer would only rotate on the x axis (horizontal.

Are there any third party products that may offer a solution?  If I have to build it from scratch, are there any suggestions on where to start (i prefer silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search : http://kit3d.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547098.aspx for silverlight 3d foundation